# Reproducing OpenCV imshow() and waitKey() with matplotlib

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

The following code works well on Windows but I need to run it on Ubuntu and it seems that `cv2.imshow()` is not supported. I'm looking for an alternative using **matplotlib** or **any other library which runs on Ubuntu**.

It works as follows:

I have a list of frames, a frame being a `numpy` array representing an RGB image. I loop through the frames, show the current one with `cv2.imshow()` and use `waitKey()` to register an action, either keep the frame (append it to another list) or dismiss it. I need the image to appear in the same window as the others.

The code:

```
"""
    frames is a list of 3-d numpy array representing an RGB image.
"""
keeped_frames = []
frame_index = 0
frames_upper_bound = len(frames)
for frame in frames:
    print('Showing frame {} / {}'.format(frame_index + 1,frames_upper_bound))
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
    if key == ord('0'):
        print('Not appending frame {} / {} to list'.format(frame_index + 1, frames_upper_bound))
    elif key == ord('1'):
        print('Appending frame {} / {} to list'.format(frame_index + 1, frames_upper_bound))
        keeped_frames.append(frame)
    elif key == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
    frame_index += 1
```

I tried with `plt.imshow()` on a loop but it creates new windows every time. Even if this is fixed, how can I easily register keyboard action and quickly switch to the next frame?
With `cv2` it works really well, I can keep the key down and frames just pass pretty fast; since I need to annotate thousands of frames this way, I'd like something similar.

Can I replicate this behavior with matplotlib or any other library which runs on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Surely, you can use the `imshow` method of `matplotlib.pyplot` and [event handling](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) capabilities of matplotlib. You can try the following code and see if it works for you:

```
import matplotlib as mpl 
mpl.use('wxAgg')

import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# just some random data 
frames = [np.random.random((10, 10)) for _ in range(100)]
keeped_frames = [] 
i = 0

# event listener 
def press(event):
    global i
    if event.key == '1':
        print('Appending frame')
        keeped_frames.append(frames[i % 100])
    i += 1
    imgplot.set_data(frames[i % 100])
    fig.canvas.draw()

fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', press)
imgplot = ax.imshow(frames[i % 100]) 
plt.show()
```

One thing that you should be aware of is that the listener behaviour depends on the backend you're using. In `Qt5Agg` one key press fires one `key_press` event whether you hold the key or not, and in `wxAgg` key holding fires continious press and release events (the behaviour you desire, I guess).